# How can I randomly select items into multiple lists, with each list being unique?

Tags: excel

Say I have 5 groups with 10 spaces for people in each. I want to randomly select and place people from a list of 100 until the groups are filled.

I understand how to do this with one list (ie randomly finding 10 names from the list), but I'm unsure how to do this given that people can't be in multiple groups. I need to somehow be randomly selecting the people for the second group from a pool of the 100 - the people selected in the first group, etc.

Any thoughts about how to go about doing this?

Comment: Shuffle the 100 and then take the first 50?

Answer (score 1):

With your list in column A:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($A$1:$A$100)/((COUNTIF(C$1:C1,$A$1:$A$100)=0)*(COUNTIF($B$2:B$11,$A$1:$A$100)=0)),RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA($A$1:$A$100)-COUNTA(C$1:C1)-COUNTA($B$2:B$11)+1)))
```

Notes:

- `C$1:C1` needs to refer to the cell above the left top cell in which the formula is placed
- `$B$2:B$11` needs to point to the cells to the left of the groups and they must be empty
- `$A$1:$A$100` is your data set of names(I used 1 to 100)

[image]